# ZF1 setDestination throws 'The given destination is not writable' exception on simultaneous upload

Tags: php, zend-framework

I used this bunch of code on my local and it's working fine.

`$httpAdapter->setDestination('/tmp/')->addFilter('Rename', $new_name));`

In most of the cases it works properly on prod, but in simultaneous upload it throws exception.
Please give me a valid solution. It's cracking me on production.

Comment: not sure but maybe the error is thrown because ``The given destination is not writeable`` so either you don't have the correct permissions set for this directory or the path don't expects the path you are trying to write on production

Comment: Could you show us code setting value for $new_name variable?

Comment: @ins0previous version **"1.11.2"** it checks using php function like
 `if (!is_writable($destination))` 
But in current **"1.12.7"** version (file '/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/File/Transfer/Adapter/Abstract.php line no. 1434), checks like
`$tempFile = rtrim($path, "/\\");
$tempFile .= '/' . 'test.1';
$result = @file_put_contents($tempFile, 'TEST');
if ($result == false) {
    return false;
}
$result = @unlink($tempFile);
if ($result == false) {
    return false;
}
return true;` **In the case of simultaneous Upload it breaks while checking file_put_contents() or unlink()**